# Tasklist Remote doesnt work

Tags: windows

GoodMorning all,

I am having some problems with the tasklist /s [servername] -u [user] -p [password]

I am on an windows 7 machine and i whant to view the tasks on my windows xp.

So i do this

tasklist /s \192.168.1.105 -u Administrator -p MyPass

The error i am recieving is unknown user or invalid password.

I am 100% positive that the username and password is correct cause i also log in with those credentials on my windows xp pc.

When i am on my windows xp and willing to do tasklist to my windows 7 pc its working fine.

Both PC's dont have an domein but are in the same WORKGROUP

Services are started on win xp. No firewall is active.
I also tried PSTools but also that one is not connecting to the windows XP machine.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: try to specify the remote computername before username like `-u xp_computername\Administrator`. I guess it's a typo but you wrote `\192.168.1.165`, it should be `192.168.1.165` or `\\192.168.1.165`

Comment: Nope also that aint working. And yes it was an typo.
I know have this

tasklist /s \\192.168.1.105 -u computername\Administrator -p MyPass
Still saying username or password invalid

Comment: you should take a look here : http://superuser.com/questions/454905/tasklist-remote-login-failure

Comment: I already did all of the things listed in there.

Still i cant connect with tasklist

Comment: are you able to ping the remote host ? run psexec \\192.168.1.168 cmd ?